# Python - How to pass elements stored in an array into a function?

Tags: python, numpy

All,

I'm new to python, so hopefully this is not a dumb question, but I have not been able to find out directions/information of how to do this task.

I am trying to create a program that determines if a given pixel is within a certain region.  The method I found that recommended how to test this involves calculating polygonal areas.  In this case, that would involve the shoelace function, which I have already found.  The polygon coordinates are stored in a 2-dimensional array as [(x,y),(x1,y1),(x2,y2)...].

The given set of test coordinates and the function representing the shoelace function are below:

```
import numpy as np
testCoords = [(201,203)...(275,203)]

def polyArea(x,y):
    return 0.5 * np.abs(np.dot(x, np.roll(y,1)) - np.dot(y, np.roll(x, 1)))
```

How do I pass the coordinates as stored in the 2-dimensional array into the shoelace function?

Comment: I see there are already 2 correct answers to your question but I have a question for you: How does the area of the polygon help you determine if some point (x0, y0) is within the polygon?  I think the standard ways for solving the point-in-polygon probing are the Ray casting algorithm and the Winding number algorithm described in this Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon. Am I missing something?

Comment: Inexperience on my part, that's what is missing.  Looked up ray casting for a bit, and then I discovered that I could just import shapely and accomplish what I wanted in 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `polyArea` expects two arrays of `x` and `y` coordinates. Your `testCoords` variable is a list of several points represented by their `(x, y)` coordinates. We will turn the later into a shape that works well, by converting it to a numpy array and **transposing** it:

```
x, y = np.array(testCoords).transpose() # Often, `.transpose()` is abbreviated as `.T`
```

That will give you `x == [201, ..., 275]` and `y == [203, ..., 203]`.

Answer (score 0):

U just need to get the given pixel's x and y coordinate. Get the index of it (if needed) with:

```
my_pixel_coordinates = (260, 203)
testCoords = [(201,203), ... (275,203)] #your pixel position array
i = testCoords.index(my_pixel_coordinates)
```

And then get the x and y coordinates using your testCoords:

```
area = polyArea(testCoords[i][0], testCoords[i][1])
#'i' is the index of the pixel and 0 the first value (x) and 1 the second (y)
```

You can get any Array's values using the squared brackets

Comment: You are calculating the area of a polygon with a single point as data?

Comment: Seems like i missread the question a little bit.  It would still work when using a for loop, but using np functions is faster.